# Magic margin on bottom

Tags: css, padding, margin, spacing

can anyone please tell me where the margin/padding in for the pictures come from?
it has on the bottom 4px extra and I can't seem to find where it is from ...
doesn't matter in what div I put it, it is always there...

http://vaneverbroeck.be/didier/#!/

Comment: You have 8 levels of DIV's from the BODY to the IMG elements. Is that really necessary? The layout doesn't look that complicated (I could do that layout with 4 levels of DIV's).

Comment: use Chrome inspect element or Firefox Firebug extension and you will easily get the element with html and the css. on the style, change anything you want like @Haza said `absolute` to see the result immediately without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try adding float:left to your images, the bottom margin should disappear.

Comment: No :) I can explain a lot of CSS strangeness, but this is just one of those weird things that makes no sense (at least not to me anyway)...

Comment: Apparently it's because images are effectively treated as inline text, and this means that there is a space at the bottom for descenders (e.g. 'y' and 'g').

Answer (score 1):

They are all positioned using `absolute` attributes in your css. That's why there is nomargin or padding between the images.

This is, on my mind, handle by the javascript on the page. You should take a look on the script/plugin that handle your mosaic and check there is there is an option to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#content` has an inline-style height of **578px**:

```
<div id="content" style="position: relative; height: 578px; " class="masoned">
```

If you adjust the height, you will be able to achieve what you want.